# How to sort a listbox without changing the index

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, listbox

i've got a listbox which I fill from a List. The strings are properties of objects in another list. When selecting something from the list, i use the index for selecting the related object (which of course has the same index as its name in the List). But when i sort the list (by name) the index of each string changes, so they suddenly are related to the wrong object.

So my question, is there a possibility for sorting the list, without changing its index.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Tag` property you can avoid having to handle the indices at all by just attaching your object to the `ListItem`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
{
    var lItem = new ListBoxItem();
    lItem.Tag = myObjects[i];
    // do some other things...
}
```

So later you can do this:

```
ListBoxItem li = // again the selected item
MyObject obj = li.Tag as MyObject;
```

If you really want to handle the indices, you could add the original index as `Tag` to your items. That way the order they appear in doesn't interfer with your original order of objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
{
    var lItem = new ListBoxItem();
    lItem.Tag = i;
    // add other values to your item
}
```

And then later:

```
ListBoxItem li = // your selected item
MyObject obj = myObjects[(int)li.Tag];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check by the value intead of the index. The value always be the one you look for. The index in the listbox corresponds to the place an object takes in it starting from the top, so when you sort it, the index will change.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @germi's answer, but here's an alternative:

1. Create an array of indices of the same size as the list of strings.
2. Create an array that's a copy of the strings (this is necessary because of the next step, which requires arrays rather than lists)
3. Use [`Array.Sort<TKey, TValue>(TKey[] keys, TValue[] items)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort the strings AND the indices together.
4. Use the sorted array of strings for the Listbox.
5. When you get an index back from the Listbox, use it to look up the original index via the sorted indices array.

For example, consider this code:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

var stringsArr = strings.ToArray();
var indices    = Enumerable.Range(0, strings.Count).ToArray();

Array.Sort(stringsArr, indices);

for (int i = 0; i < stringsArr.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has original index {1}", stringsArr[i], indices[i]);

// Add stringsArr to the listbox.
// If an index from the listbox is lbi, then the original index of the item
// that it refers to will be indices[lbi]
```